# Some weird C compile error in Windows 7

Tags: c, visual-c++

When I compiled the following method `geohash_move_x` with VS 2013(Windows version Redis), it give me many error such as below, however this issue just happened at **win7**, in **win10** there is no error.

> error  188 error C2275: “uint64_t”: this expression is illegal
>
> error  189 error C2146: grammar error: lack“;”
>
> error  190 error C2065: “x”: un declared identitier

```
static void geohash_move_x(GeoHashBits *hash, int8_t d) {
if (d == 0)
    return;

uint64_t x = hash->bits & 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaULL;
uint64_t y = hash->bits & 0x5555555555555555ULL;

uint64_t zz = 0x5555555555555555ULL >> (64 - hash->step * 2);

if (d > 0) {
    x = x + (zz + 1);
} else {
    x = x | zz;
    x = x - (zz + 1);
}

x &= (0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaULL >> (64 - hash->step * 2));
hash->bits = (x | y);
```

}

[image]

Comment: Have you included <cstdint> (or <stdint.h> if it's C)?

Comment: The file include #include "geohash.h" , and  "geohash.h" include the following 
#include <stddef.h> 

#include <stdint.h>

#include <stdint.h>

Comment: Please mark the code line 188, 189 and 190 in your question.

Comment: The source code from the below URL https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/tree/3.2

Comment: @grek40 , hundreds of error, the above three just  three of them, and there is no any error when compile in Windows 10 , so I don't think it should be a code issue, it maybe be a configuration issue.

Comment: please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: @Michael , please get the solution  from URL below, and compile it with vs 2013 in win7, then you can repro the issue.
https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/tree/3.2

Comment: Thats far from *minimal* :D

Comment: @Jason note the word _minimal_ in my comment.

Comment: @grek40, the error happens when compile a solution, it's very difficult to provide Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @grek40 , if you can download the open source solution, then the issue should be at lest satisfy the Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: What is the first error?

Comment: @Michael Walz , it is hard to just extract the Minimal code from the solution, and if I do this , maybe the error doesn't happens, anyway the method   geohash_move_x in the file geohash.c of the solution maybe one kind of minimal.

Comment: @Bob, if I just compile the project geohash, the three errors I post are just the first three errors.

Comment: I have no idea if there is kind person can download the code from the gitpub https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/tree/3.2 , and compile it with VS 2013 in win7 to repro the error.

Comment: I can't and won't download that project right now. Some sanity checks: [is the Windows 7 / VS 2013 a 32 or 64 bit version](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/issues/344)? What about Windows 10? [Any spaces in the project file path](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/issues/412)?

Comment: @Jason Open the project properties, and tell us what Platform toolset you have under Configuration Properties->General. It just compiles fine here under Vusual Studio 215 running on Windows 7. The platform toolset here is `Visual Studio 2013 (v120)`.

Comment: @Michael, my configuration also Visual Studio 2013 (v120).

Comment: @Michael, I would try to install Vusual Studio 215 to see if it compile ok.

Comment: @grek40 win7 64 , I remember the VS  only has 32 bit version.  no space in the project file path.

Comment: @Jason: You are contradicting yourself. You claim that the first error is C2275, but your screenshot shows C2223 as the first error. How come? **Start with the first error**. The first error in your screenshot is C2223. Where does it happen? What does it say? Post the full error message. We are not interested in screenshots of the fancy "Errors" window with those colorful icons. Post the full text from the normal textual "Build Output" window.

Comment: @AnT, The first error C2275  mentioned above is the error when I just compile the project geohash , while the errors in screenshots is for the entirely solution, which contains many projects.

Comment: @AnT, it is not a C grammar issue, it should be a configuration issue,as I can compile it successfully in win 10

Comment: `hash` may not be a good variable name, is there any chance that VS misinterpret it as `std::hash`?

Comment: @Bob__ no, function parameter would shadow that even if `using namespace std;` were in effect

Comment: @all, successfully if I build it with visual studio 20015 in win7 .Based on the URL https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/tree/3.2, it should be ok compile it with VS 2013.
==========

"9>  RedisServer.vcxproj -> C:\redis32\msvs\x64\Debug\redis-server.exe
========== Build: 9 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped =========="

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to investigate the output of pre-processor for your `geohash.c` file and compare it for VS 2013 and VS2015 ( or VS2013 on Win 7 and VS2013 Win 10). Probably it will give you an answer why compiler has a problem with `uint64_t` type.

To configure VS to output the preprocessed file go to `geohash` -> `geohash.c` file and open it's **Property page**. Modify **Generate Preprocessed File** property to **Yes**. In your product, *Debug* solution configuration builds *Release* configuration, so be careful to change options in proper project configuration. Or do it for all of them.

If everything configured well you will find the pre-processed file in:

```
msvs\geohash\Win32\Release\geohash.i
```

During problem investigation you may need to compile the `geohash.i`. Open the [Developer Command Prompt for VS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859%28v=vs.120%29.aspx), `cd` into the `msvs\geohash\Win32\Release` directory and run the compiler:

```
cl /Tp geohash.i
```